# How do I make an input field accept only letters in javaScript?

Tags: javascript, validation, input

How do I make an input field accept only letters in javaScript?
now i need it to accept only letters?

Comment: Java isn't Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use HTML5:

```
<form>
    <input type='text' pattern='[A-Za-z\\s]*'/>
</form>
```

If you only want to do it with javascript:

```
function alpha(value) {
  var regex = /^[a-zA-Z]*$/;
  if (regex.test(value)) {
      return true;
  }
  else {
      return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Either way, don't forget to recheck on the server side!